# Azure storage server auto includes x-ms-request-id header in get blob operation

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying list blob operation followed by get blob operation. List blob works well but when it comes to get blob , the server auto includes x-ms-request-id in the header string resulting in unmatched calculated string.
Error goes like:

The MAC signature found in the HTTP request  is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET
Is there a way to stop server from auto including x-ms-request-id ?
package com.azure;

```
    //import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Base64;
    import java.util.Base64.Decoder;
    import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
    //import java.util.Calendar;
    //import java.util.TimeZone;
    //import java.util.Date;
    import javax.crypto.Mac;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    //import java.text.DateFormat;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    public class Util {
    
        // static SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        // static Date now= new Date();
    
        // static String strDate = fmt.format(now);
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    
        }
    
    
    
      
    
        public static String signGetBlobRequestSK(String request, String account, String key,String now) throws Exception
        {
            //static SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            //fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            //String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
    
            String signedStr = Util.unsignedGetBlobRequestSK(account, now);
    
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
            Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
            mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(decoder.decode(key), "HmacSHA256"));
            String authKey = new String(encoder.encode(mac.doFinal(signedStr.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
            //Byte authKeyDecoded = Byte.decode(authKey);
            String auth = "SharedKey " + account + ":" + authKey;
    
            return auth;
        }
 public static String unsignedGetBlobRequestSK(String account, String now) throws Exception
    {

        //fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));


        // String currentTimestamp = fmt.format(now) + " GMT";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("GET\n"); // method
        sb.append('\n'); // content encoding
        sb.append('\n'); // content language
        sb.append('\n'); // content length
        sb.append('\n'); // md5 (optional)
        sb.append('\n'); // content type
        sb.append('\n'); // legacy date
        sb.append('\n'); // if-modified-since
        sb.append('\n'); // if-match
        sb.append('\n'); // if-none-match
        sb.append('\n'); // if-unmodified-since
        sb.append('\n'); // range
        sb.append("x-ms-date:" + now +'\n'); // headers
        sb.append("x-ms-version:2019-12-12\n");
        sb.append("/" + account + '/'+ "test" + "/Test%20File%20for%20GMS.xml");

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Please can you add the code you tried.

Comment: I have added code to initial question, Jagrati.